# How do I create a LibGDX text input inside a window? (no pop up)

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx

I have been working on a libGDX project and was wondering if I could create a login screen with the use of some kind of text inputs. I have been looking all around for text input fields, but the only one I can seem to find are those that pop up, which I don't really want to use.
My project is a desktop game only and uses the screen implementations combinede with a game super class.

Is there any other way to get text input inside the window, so not as a pop up?

Comment: There's scene2d's `TextField` which does exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment, the right way to make a login screen is to use Scene2d.ui and its TextField. Check out the Scene2d.ui wiki page and Skin Composer to get going.